# Cross object field update

Tags: update

I have an object called offers. When I update a field, called Offer Status, in my offers object, I want to update another field in my Contact Object to reflect the change. Is there a way to do this in the workflow rules? If not, is there a way to do this without hard-coding?

Comment: Is there any relationship between offers and contact? If yes then you can use a field update action in workflow or you can even use process builder.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Contact is related to Offers, if you create workflow rule on offers and use workflow actions type- New Field Update, you can update a field on contact object.

[image]

Comment: process builder allows for updating related records; workflow is much more constrained

Comment: I agree. Process builder is more flexible.